# Передача параметра в Asyncio из модуля в модуль

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Мне необходимо передать параметры объекта класса "formatdf", изменяемые в функции "process" в модуль "Tests.restapi_quart" для ответа на GET запрос. Как это сделать? Пробовал использовать Asyncio.Queue и фреймворк contextvars, но так и не разобрался как правильно передавать.

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import closing
import db_cl, tks_db
from formdf_cl import FormatDF
import Tests.restapi_quart
# contextvars


getinfofromtks = tks_db.TKS()
formatdf = FormatDF()
dbb = db_cl.MyDatabase('mydb.ini')


async def get_some_data():
    # Обработка I/O - получение данных из базы
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    ans_inc, ans_out = getinfofromtks.getdf()
    return ans_inc, ans_out


async def process(ans_inc, ans_out):
    # Обработка данных на CPU
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    formatdf.leftjoin(ans_inc, ans_out)
    formatdf.make_count() # подсчет и сохранение параметров в объекте класса


async def launcher_main():
    while True:
        ans_inc, ans_out = await get_some_data()  # Блокирующий вызов - ожидание поступления новой порции данных

        asyncio.ensure_future(process(ans_inc, ans_out))  # Неблокирующий вызов - обработка данных на CPU


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(launcher_main(),Tests.restapi_quart.app.run_task(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with closing(asyncio.get_event_loop()) as event_loop:
        event_loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Модуль "Tests.restapi_quart":

```
import quart
from quart import request
import json
import time
import db_cl

dbb = db_cl.MyDatabase('mydb.ini')
app = quart.Quart(__name__)


def resp(code, data):
    return quart.Response(
        status=code,
        mimetype="application/json",
        response=to_json(data)
    )


def resp_json(code, data):
    return quart.Response(
        status=code,
        mimetype="application/json",
        response=data
    )

def to_json(data):
    return json.dumps(data) + "\n"

@app.route('/api/status2', methods=['GET'])
def get_status():
    timestamp = request.args.get("timestamp")
    timenow = request.args.get("timenow")
    lastone = request.args.get("lastone")
    button = request.args.get("button")
    if timestamp:
        return resp_json(200, dbb.fetch_all_as_df("select * from statistic where timestamp >= " + "'" +
                                                  time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(float(timestamp)))
                                                  + "';").to_json())
    elif timenow:
        return resp(200, {"time is:": time.time()})
    elif button:
        return resp(200, {"ok": **передать параметр сюда**})
    elif lastone:
        return resp_json(200, dbb.fetch_all_as_df('select * from statistic ORDER BY timestamp DESC  LIMIT 1').to_json())
    else:
        return resp(200, {"", "ask me about time"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас всё в одном треде, так что прицепите formatdf к классу приложения

```
async def main():
    Tests.restapi_quart.app.config["formatdf"] = formatdf
    await asyncio.gather(launcher_main(),Tests.restapi_quart.app.run_task(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000))
```

И смотрите атрибуты

```
elif button:
    return resp(200, {"ok": app.config["formatdf"].attr})
```

Comment: GET по button возвращает пустой словарь {}
после того как запихнул строчку Tests.restapi_quart.app.config["formatdf"] = formatdf в функцию process() стало возвращать то что нужно! Спасибо!

Comment: слева от ответа галочка. Странно что пусто, возможно это связанно с блокировками.